# How to generate URLs for a custom URL shortener?

Tags: php, database-design, mysql, url

Due to some issues with other shorteners like goo.gl (disabling my links for example) I want to create my own URL shortener.

I am looking to have a single table that will contain the following columns :-

```
links_id - autoincrement id
url - the actual full URL
abbreviation - the shortened version
```

In a nutshell, when a new link is added to the table, I will insert the URL into the table and give this a unique abbreviated value, obviously if an existing URL is found it won't need to re-add the URL.

My question is what is the best way to generate such abbreviations that are fast to produce and are as unique as possible and not simple to guess. In addition how many number of characters would people recommend, for instance, if I had an abbreviation of 6 characters, how many unique combinations would this provide me based I am using the standard characters as used by other URL shorteners.

I will be using PHP/MySQL, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It is impossible to generate unique hashes, that is the very nature of hashes.

Comment: You're operating under the assumption that the identifiers used by URL shorteners are hashes.  They aren't.

Comment: Why is "not simple to guess" a requirement? And what do you mean by that; that if I have shortened URL AAAB1 do you want me to not be able to know URL AAAB2 probably exists and was created shortly after mine. Or do you want me to not be able to know that AAAB2 is actually Google.com?

Comment: Before the nitpickers come and close the question, I took the freedom and replaced the word "hash" by "abbreviation".

Comment: @JörgWMittag Long hashes (SHA256 or better) can be treated as unique for all purposes. But of course that doesn't work for a url *shortener*.

Comment: @RichardTingle A "not simple to guess" might be necessary on certain type of users. A lot of editors do preview sites on CMS and send shortened URLs to customers. These URLs are not for a public audience. This is a bad practice but very common. Imho, "not simple to guess" is a valid use case.

Comment: Have you tried [YOURLS](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS)?

Answer (score 7):

URL shortners do not use hashes to generate the shortened URL. Hashes are not (by their very design) unique.

A common way to encode URLs is to simply take the `links_id` value and convert it to [base 62](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964197/converting-a-number-base-10-to-base-62-a-za-z0-9) (ie a-z, A-Z and 0-9, giving 62 values per "digit") and use that as the URL.

Comment: Long hashes (SHA256 or better) can be treated as unique for all purposes. The utter unfeasability of ever finding two different inputs with the same hash is their most important design property. But of course that doesn't work for a url *shortener*.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, You are of course correct. But I tend to think of those long hashes as GUIDS & do shorthand GUID = unique; hash = non-unique & for eg hash tables.

Comment: Concerning the "not simple to guess", the `links_id` might not be the perfect solution, especially with auto_increment in MySQL. A script could easily extract all URLs from the shortener. Depending on the use case, this might not be intended.

Comment: @Trendfischer: this is probably a red herring, see the Richard Tingle's comment below the question. As long as the OP does not clarify this, I would assume he has not really thought about what he asking for here.

Comment: @DocBrown Sorry, I've seen the comment too late, made my answer to this below the question.

Answer (score 3):

The idea on creating an URL shortener is using short strings to abbreviate the URL. Most common hashing functions create a long hex decimal string, which is longer than necessary, even abbreviated. I would go with the following design:

- Query the database, if the URL is already existing, return the saved short string
- Create a random number the size approximate on how many URLs you will expect in your database
- Convert the number to a base64 string or base36 (using a-z instead a-f, e.g. see the function base_convert for php), do not forget to [replace URL specific characters on a base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications)
- Run a query against your database to test, if the random string is already in your database, if yes, repeat the generation
- Save the link in your database with the generated random short string

Answer (score 0):

For every new insertion you would be going to a db, finding the next number, converting it into a shortened url which is going to be time consuming. Why not have your database allot integers in an increment of 1000s to the compute machine so that you are only saving the record once and not twice (find the next id from db + save the record in the db).

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.